# Squashing commits that are in a pull request in GitHub, git rebase not opening my text editor

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to merge my last 4 commits into one (the commits are already in a pull request on GitHub).

I've set up my default editor with:

```
git config --global core.editor "'C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe' -w"
```

I did not get a confirmation message (should I?), I'm on Windows 8.

Then, I tried to rebase with:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~4
```

I got the following message:

```
Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/name-of-my-branch
```

I though a text editor is suppose to open up with my commits and I can chose to `pick` or `squash`?

Can someone please provide me with a step-by-step answer on how to merge/squash 4 commits into 1, using Git on Windows Command Prompt.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure how to solve the problem on Windows, but I suspect it's some quoting problem with the `core.editor` string.  You *shouldn't* get a confirmation message when setting the value, but you definitely *should* get a chance to edit the rebase plan in the editor.  I would try editing your `~/.gitconfig` file directly, to at least take one level of shell quoting out of the picture.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, for some reason it was hung up on "notepad" and I actually had to rename my vim to "notepad" in the Git -> usr -> bin folder, to trick it to at least open vim. Even changing the path in ~/.gitconfig to vim or anything else wouldn't work. It works now, but it's a very weird solution.

Answer (score 0):

Check commit in the branch using command

```
$ git log --oneline
```

you will get result like

```
f0d5199 changes in end points
a4cb008 changes
2e1f2c2 Ui Changes
d70542c Text changes
cb3c304 remove file
```

You want to sqaush last 4 commits i.e (f0d5199, a4cb008, 2e1f2c2, d70542c) 
and make it single commit.

Now take 5th commit i.e cb3c304 and use command

```
$ git rebase -i cb3c304
```

a default editor will be open like vim, nano. In my case it is showing like

```
pick d70542c Text changes
pick 2e1f2c2 Ui Changes
pick a4cb008 changes
pick f0d5199 changes in end points

# Rebase cb3c304..f0d5199 onto cb3c304 (2 commands)
#
# Commands:
# p, pick = use commit
# r, reword = use commit, but edit the commit message
# e, edit = use commit, but stop for amending
# s, squash = use commit, but meld into previous commit
# f, fixup = like "squash", but discard this commit's log message
# x, exec = run command (the rest of the line) using shell
# d, drop = remove commit
#
# These lines can be re-ordered; they are executed from top to bottom.
#
# If you remove a line here THAT COMMIT WILL BE LOST.
#
# However, if you remove everything, the rebase will be aborted.
#
# Note that empty commits are commented out
```

Now you can pick or squash commit as per your choice, like

```
pick d70542c Text changes
s 2e1f2c2 Ui Changes
s a4cb008 changes
s f0d5199 changes in end points
```

changed 3 commit(sha) 'pick to s', and save ,again editer will open, again save .New sha (commit id) has been created 51c2b3b with 'Text changes' message.

Now all 4 commits changes will come in one single commit i.e (sha 51c2b3b).

Squashing is done. Now check logs

```
$ git log --oneline

51c2b3b Text changes
```

Answer (score 0):

Searching "core.editor sublime" on google I've found that the possible solution could be the following:

```
git config --global core.editor "subl -n -w"
```